# JScrollPane won't scroll over JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a JFrame in which I am drawing a lot of images in a large grid. My window is not big enough to contain the entire grid, so I want to use a JScrollPane that will allow me to show certain parts of the grid in the window.

My problem is that I cannot scroll. When I made it so the scrollbars always show up, they appear to already cover the entire area.

[image]

As you can see, the scrollbars give the impression that the entire area is shown in the window. However, if I resize it, you'll notice that is not the case at all!

[image]

And the scrollbars continue to say they cover the entire area.

(*Note that the numbers in the grid are actually 16 by 16 px images but in order to make a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, I replaced the images with coordinate strings*.)

Here is my code for the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;


public class Main {
    public static int[][] tiles;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.run();
    }
}

class Foo {
    public void run(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Panel panel = new Panel();

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(512,448));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);

        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

        Main.tiles = new int[32][32];

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            panel.repaint();    
        }
    }

}

class Panel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
        paintScreen(g);
    }

    private void paintScreen(Graphics g){
        int x =0, y =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Main.tiles.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Main.tiles[i].length; j++){
                g.drawString(i + " " + j, x*32, y*32);
                y++;
            }
            y=0;
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is:

**Q: Why is the `JScrollPane` not allowing me to scroll over the `JPanel`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem looks to be here:

```
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(512,448));
```

where you constrain the JPanel held by the JScrollPane to a specific size, not allowing it to expand. Never do this. Instead constrain the JScrollPane or its view port.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Main {
   public static int[][] tiles;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Foo foo = new Foo();
      foo.run();
   }
}

class Foo {
   public void run() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      Panel panel = new Panel();

      // !! panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(512,448));
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
      scrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(512, 448));

      scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      frame.add(scrollPane);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.pack();

      Main.tiles = new int[32][32];

      while (true) {
         try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         panel.repaint();
      }
   }

}

class Panel extends JPanel {

   private static final int PREF_W = 1200;
   private static final int PREF_H = 1200;

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      paintScreen(g);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private void paintScreen(Graphics g) {
      int x = 0, y = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < Main.tiles.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < Main.tiles[i].length; j++) {
            g.drawString(i + " " + j, x * 32, y * 32);
            y++;
         }
         y = 0;
         x++;
      }
   }
}
```

---

**Edit**
Attempt at improving version based on MadProgrammer's recommendation:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;

public class Main {
   public static int[][] tiles;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Foo foo = new Foo();
      foo.run();
   }
}

class Foo {
   public void run() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      NumberPanel panel = new NumberPanel();

      // !! panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(512,448));
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
      // !! scrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(512, 448));

      scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      frame.add(scrollPane);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.pack();

      Main.tiles = new int[32][32];

      while (true) {
         try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         panel.repaint();
      }
   }

}

class NumberPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

   private static final int PREF_W = 1200;
   private static final int PREF_H = 1200;
   private static final int VP_WIDTH = 512;
   private static final int VP_HEIGHT = 448;

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      paintScreen(g);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private void paintScreen(Graphics g) {
      int x = 0, y = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < Main.tiles.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < Main.tiles[i].length; j++) {
            g.drawString(i + " " + j, x * 32, y * 32);
            y++;
         }
         y = 0;
         x++;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
      return new Dimension(VP_WIDTH, VP_HEIGHT);
   }

   @Override
   public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
      // TODO Consider improving
      return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
      // TODO Consider improving
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain how to constrain the JScrollPane or its view port?

Comment: @Chronicle: for example see code above. Note that it is usually frowned upon to directly set preferred sizes.

Comment: You could also use the getPreferredScrollableViewportSize from the Scrollable interface

Comment: `pack()` first then `setVisible()` ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: thanks! I will try to implement this!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm trying to understand the benefit of the second code. You're still overwriting `getPreferredSize` which you said is frowned upon. Is it that it performs more efficiently or faster?

Comment: @Chronicle: Overriding `getPreferredSize()` is OK. It's directly calling `setPreferredSize(...)` that is frowned upon.